# DataFrame from list of dicts with relative order of keys maintained in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of dictionaries (row data) like below:

```py
from typing import List, Dict, Any

testDict: List[Dict[str, Any]] = list(
    (
        {"A": 0.1, "B": 1, "E": "ABE"},
        {"A": 0.11, "B": 20, "C": 0.2, "E": "ABCE"},
        {"A": 0.11, "B": 3, "D": 33, "E": "ABDE"},
        {"A": 0.13, "B": 40, "C": 0.5, "D": 23, "E": "ABCDE"},
    )
)
```

```py
testDict
[{'A': 0.1, 'B': 1, 'E': 'ABE'},
 {'A': 0.11, 'B': 20, 'C': 0.2, 'E': 'ABCE'},
 {'A': 0.11, 'B': 3, 'D': 33, 'E': 'ABDE'},
 {'A': 0.13, 'B': 40, 'C': 0.5, 'D': 23, 'E': 'ABCDE'}]
```

I want to convert this `testDict` to a pandas dataframe. So, I did this:

```py
testDf: pd.DataFrame = pd.json_normalize(data=testDict, max_level=1)
testDf

   A      B     E   C     D
0  0.10   1    ABE  NaN   NaN
1  0.11  20   ABCE  0.2   NaN
2  0.11   3   ABDE  NaN  33.0
3  0.13  40  ABCDE  0.5  23.0
```

However, I want the relative order of the keys to be maintained in the column names like `[A, B, C, D, E]` (or `[A, B, D, C, E]` only if I don't have the last entry).

I've 100K such row data with total number of keys as 256 in the actual data. Is there any easy way to achieve this? Or do I need to merge these key names like merge-sort to build the column name orders and use that?

### Update 1:

I'm not looking for how to lexiographically sort the columns here. In each dict, keys are already in specific order. For any row, the relative order of the keys should remain the same. My sample list could be following:

```py
[{'XYZ': 0.1, 'ABC': 1, 'PQR': 'ABE'},
 {'XYZ': 0.11, 'ABC': 20, 'KLM': 0.2, 'PQR': 'ABCE'},
 {'XYZ': 0.11, 'ABC': 3, 'DEF': 33, 'PQR': 'ABDE'},
 {'XYZ': 0.13, 'ABC': 40, 'KLM': 0.5, 'DEF': 23, 'PQR': 'ABCDE'}]
```

In this case, final column order should be ['XYZ', 'ABC', 'KLM', 'DEF', 'PQR']

Answer (score 0):

You can just define the dataframe with testdict as value and explicitly declare the order of columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(testDict, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
```

this prints as:

```
      A   B    C     D      E
0  0.10   1  NaN   NaN    ABE
1  0.11  20  0.2   NaN   ABCE
2  0.11   3  NaN  33.0   ABDE
3  0.13  40  0.5  23.0  ABCDE
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to explicitly declare columns, yo can sort them in place:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(testDict).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Comment: Yes, but then I need to build the column list and hence I referred to the merge-sort like merge. My question is if there is any simpler method.

Comment: Does this help then: Run  `df.sort_index(axis=1)` after creating dataframe then print df. See edit in answer.

Comment: Please check update in the question to clarify the requirements further.

Comment: Will you always have at least one element with ALL the columns included?

Comment: Not necessarily. The first and the last key for every row will be same, if that helps.

Comment: In that case you would have to predetermine the order. Say you had the following data:`[{'xy': 5, 'bb': 7, 'aa': 3}, {'xy': 2, 'mn': 3, 'aa': 4}]`. What order should they be in? How do you determine which of 'bb' or 'mn' should be first?

Comment: For 'bb' and 'mm' in this case, we can put in any order ie both ['xy', 'bb', 'mn', 'aa'] and ['xy', 'mn', 'bb', 'aa'] are valid (and these are only 2 valid cases). For run-to-run consistency, we may put those in lexiographical order.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, with your Update 1 I get it.

Note that you have to use python versions higher than 3.6 otherwise the order of the keys in the dictionaries is not guaranteed.

That said, you need to go through all the dictionaries and mark the maximum index of each key, then just sort them in ascending position order.

Then you can use the resulting list to specify the order of the columns.

You could do this in the following way:

```
import operator
        
colIndxs = {}
        
for dy in data:
 i = 0
 for key in dy.keys():
  if key in colIndxs:
   colIndxs[key] = max(colIndxs[key], i)
  else:
   colIndxs[key] = i
  i += 1
          
cols = list( dict( sorted(colIndxs.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1))) )

df = pd.DataFrame(testDict, columns=cols)
```

Comment: Please check update in the question to clarify the requirements further.

Comment: @soumeng78 Something like this?